# Knee point estimation via R code for Kmeans clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have the following code using which I am able to plot the WSS curve to spot the knee so that I can choose the value of K for KMeans clustering.

```
# To find WSS 
findWSS <- function(data) {
if (VERBOSE) {
    print(paste("[TRACER] Finding WSS.."))
}
start <- Sys.time()
wss <- (nrow(data)-1)*sum(apply(data,2,var))

for (i in 2:length(unique(data))) {
    wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(data, centers=i)$withinss)
}
if (ENABLE_PLOTS) {
    plot(1:length(unique(data)), wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters", ylab="Within groups sum of squares")
}
end <- Sys.time()
if (ENABLE_MEASUREMENTS && VERBOSE) {
    print(paste("[TIMER] Finding WSS:", difftime(end, start), "secs"))
}
}
```

The following is the representation of the plot i get:

[image]

The observed knee in the above image is 3 for example. But I wanted to compute this knee programmatically in R

Any thoughts on how i can go about the same?

Comment: What is your statistical criterion of the "observed knee"? When I do this with a 100x2 matrix constructed with 2 groups (ala the example in `?kmeans`) there is no definite knee and the point on the curve with minimum distance to the origin, which might be one definition of the "knee" would suggest that there were between 6-9 groups.

Comment: You could try to implement the gap-statistic by [Hastie et al](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/gap.pdf). See here for a worked [example](http://blog.echen.me/2011/03/14/counting-clusters/).

Comment: thanks. I used clusGap from the library 'cluster' to do the gap statistic

Comment: In my opinion, the knee is at 2... you may notice that we disagree, so how would an algorithm find a "correct" solution? Do not trust/rely on these statistics, but *visualize* your data and inspect the clusters carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I used clusGap from 'cluster' library to help with this. Here is the code I used to solve this for anyone who wants to reference it:

```
# Compute Gap statistic (http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/gap.pdf) to identify number of clusters
# Note: This method is slow due to bootstrapping
computeGapStatistic <- function(data, KMax) {
# gap <- clusGap((data), FUN = kmeans, K.max = 8, B = 3) 
gap <- clusGap((data), FUN = kmeans, K.max = KMax, B = 3) 
if (ENABLE_PLOTS) {
    plot(gap, main = "Gap statistic for the Nursing shift data")
}
clusterCount <- with(gap,maxSE(Tab[,"gap"],Tab[,"SE.sim"]))
if (VERBOSE) {
    print(paste("gap statsitics: ", gap[[1]]))
    print(paste("K: ", clusterCount))
}
return(clusterCount)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I have done (less rigorous but maybe more intuitive) is to take the *differences* between WSS differences (i.e. the y-differences between points in your plot) and cluster *them*, into 2 groups. This is based on the idea that large changes are meaningful, and small ones are not, and attempting to distinguish these 'large' and 'small' clusters.

I then choose the number of groups based upon the first difference in the 'small' group, i.e. if the 'diff(k=3, k=4)' value is the first 'small' value, then the correct number of clusters is 3, because when more than 3 clusters were added, no more meaningful structure was found.

This will miss finer-grained structure if, for example the clusters are hierarchical (because it will stop too soon), but I have found it to be a nice place to start.